# Wasabi and Planout AB Testing

Tags: ab-testing, intuit-wasabi

I would like to know wasabi (https://github.com/intuit/wasabi) and planout (https://facebook.github.io/planout/docs/why-planout.html ) ab testing open source components are javascript based or reactjs based. I have not found anywhere about this. Since I am planning to integrate, test this program, i would like to know about what level of support these libs bringing in.

If anyone aware about these libs are reactJS or JS based, please update.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the lack of responses, the support for both is all but gone, if it ever existed. Both of these open source frameworks are server-side. Planout is PHP, though I've heard claims that it's been ported to other languages. Wasabi is Java.

Answer (score 0):

Planout has "production ready ports" for PHP, Java and Javascript ([source](https://facebook.github.io/planout/)). If support is important to you, it's worth noting that the Planout repo hasn't been updated since Dec 2016 ([source](https://github.com/facebook/planout)).

Wasabi is an API-driven testing framework, meaning you can use it from any language ([source](https://github.com/intuit/wasabi)). The downside of an API approach is the latency it adds for each experiment decision.

If you're looking for a server-side JS or REACT SDK for testing, you could consider [Optimizely](https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/full-stack/docs). Using SDKs mean the decision can take place in memory (no latency) using a deterministic hashing algorithm. The SDKs are open source on [Optimizely's github](https://github.com/optimizely/).

Disclaimer: I work for Optimizely.